# Dagger 2 : Presenter is null

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Need assistance in understanding why Splash Presenter is returned as null. I am following clean architecture.

```
public class SplashActivity extends BaseActivity implements HasComponent<LoginComponent> {

    @Inject
    SplashPresenter splashPresenter;

    private LoginComponent loginComponent;


    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        //setContentView(R.layout.spla);

        this.initializeInjector();
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
           // addFragment(R.id.fragmentContainer, new UserListFragment());
        }

        splashPresenter.initialize();
    }

    private void initializeInjector() {
        this.loginComponent = DaggerLoginComponent.builder()
                .applicationComponent(getApplicationComponent())
                .activityModule(getActivityModule())
                .loginModule(new LoginModule())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public LoginComponent getComponent() {
        return loginComponent;
    }
}
```

In my activity SplashPresenter is always null.

Here is the Activity Component

```
@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, modules = ActivityModule.class)
public interface ActivityComponent {
  //Exposed to sub-graphs.
  Activity activity();
}

@Module
public class ActivityModule {
  private final Activity activity;

  public ActivityModule(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
  }

  /**
  * Expose the activity to dependents in the graph.
  */
  @Provides @PerActivity Activity activity() {
    return this.activity;
  }
}
```

Here is my LoginComponent

```
 @PerActivity
    @Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, modules = {ActivityModule.class, LoginModule.class})
    public interface LoginComponent extends ActivityComponent {


}
```

Here is LoginModule

```
@Module
public class LoginModule {

    private User user;

    public LoginModule(){}

    public LoginModule(User user){this.user = user;}

    @Provides
  LoginRepository provideLoginRepository(LoginDataRepository loginRepository) {
    return loginRepository;
  }


    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    @Named("isUserLoggedIn")
    UseCase provideIsUserLoggedInUseCase(IsUserLoggedIn isUserLoggedIn){
        return isUserLoggedIn;
    }

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    @Named("login")
    UseCase provideLoginUseCase(LoginRepository loginRepository, ThreadExecutor threadExecutor, PostExecutionThread postExecutionThread){
        return new Login(user,loginRepository,threadExecutor,postExecutionThread);
    }

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    @Named("logOut")
    UseCase provideLogoutUseCase(LoginRepository loginRepository, ThreadExecutor threadExecutor, PostExecutionThread postExecutionThread){
        return new LogOut(user,loginRepository,threadExecutor,postExecutionThread);
    }
}
```

In BaseActivity I am doing following

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

  @Inject Navigator navigator;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
  }

  protected ActivityModule getActivityModule() {
    return new ActivityModule(this);
  }

}
```

Still I am unable to understand why is my presenter null in SplashActivity

Here is my Splash Presenter

```
@PerActivity
public class SplashPresenter implements  Presenter {

    private final UseCase isUserLoggedIn;

    private SplashView splashView;

    @Inject
    public SplashPresenter(@Named("isUserLoggedIn") UseCase isUserLoggedIn) {
        this.isUserLoggedIn = isUserLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution to this? Same problem here :(

Comment: Please post a solution if you were able to resolve the issue successfully.

Answer (score 0):

the instance of `loginComponent` creates after `inject method`.

move your component initializer to custom Application class. Or move to component initializer to `BaseActivity`, `inject method` to `SlashActivity`

And you makes `inject declaration` each Activity that you want to inject instance at Component interface.

Comment: Still same issue, tried this
public abstract class BaseActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initializeInjector();
    this.getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
  }

  private LoginComponent loginComponent;

  private void initializeInjector() {
    this.loginComponent = DaggerLoginComponent.builder()
            .applicationComponent(getApplicationComponent())
            .activityModule(getActivityModule())
            .loginModule(new LoginModule())
            .build();
  }